# Executing batch file located on remote machine

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a batch file that is located on a remote machine with the following line of code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(\\10.0.24.103\somePath\batchFile.bat);
```

And it blocks on this line of code. When I try to run it manually (by writing that address in Windows Explorer), it works, but I have to accept a security warning message first. I'm assuming this is why it's blocking when it's done through code...is there any way to force it to execute through code?

Comment: `is there any way to force it to execute through code?` if some program (like Windows Explorer) can do it, than you can surely do it.

Comment: Windows Explorer didn't do what I wanted, it gave me a security warning message box that I had to accept before executing the batch file. I want to execute it without any warning message that I'd have to accept first (if that really is the reason why it's blocking, I'm not sure...)

Comment: Then run your batch file with some administrative account.

Comment: Even if I open Windows Explorer as an administrator, I still get the warning message.

Comment: Every example of `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` that I can find has the executable in quotes. Try that and see if it works (I don't have C# installed so I can't test it myself). Also, I know batch can sometimes have issues with files on network paths, but this is C# so I don't know how well it handles those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding more detail to the `ProcessStartInfo` object:

```
var process = new Process();

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  CreateNoWindow = true,
  FileName = "cmd.exe",
  Arguments = "/c \"\"" + batchFile + "\"\"",
  WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardError = true,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(30000);
```

I needed to specify to use `cmd.exe`, as well as surrounding the `batchFile` path in double quotes in case there are spaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefacing it with `cmd /c`(that's a space after `/c`).

Is this IP address a Windows machine on your domain etc.

Comment: It's a Windows machine, and that causes it to throw an exception that says "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Assuming no spaces in your command line to program. `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmd /c \\10.0.24.103\somePath\batchFile.bat);` I'm no C person but normally C likes its backslashes escaped with backslashes. If we call C programs like WMIC we would need to do this `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmd /c \\\\10.0.24.103\\somePath\\batchFile.bat);`. Didn't Alexander kill you years ago.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because it works when I choose a local path on my own machine.

Comment: Still wondering why the King of Persia is asking questions after 1600 years of being dead. What is the exact wording of the security dialog. Foreign files (ie not from a Windows environment) have an alternative data stream that says "hey, prompt the user before running". CMD ignores this but explorer doesn't. Properties - General on the file will have an Unblock button. You didn't answer my question about source just said that's not it.

Comment: When opening it from Windows Explorer, I get a dialogue that says "The publisher could not be verified...". But in cmd I don't and it works fine. I actually tried System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmd.exe, \\10.0.24.103\somePath\batchFile.bat); and it seemed to run through it fine, but my batch file outputs a text file in its running directory, and I can't find that text file anywhere, so that doesn't suffice either... It's an IP address of a Windows machine running on the same network

Comment: And looking at my code in the debugger, I can see that it already has double backslashes

Comment: The normal dialog (which isn't copyable with Ctrl + C) says it doesn't have a signature. Therefore I assume the signature can't be verified (I have a few MS programs that can't be). Can you right click and Properties - Unblock.

Comment: The exe. I imagine bat files are the same.

Comment: Perhaps post screen shoots of what you are seeing

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if you right-click on any file, and click on Properties, it's the same dialogue box, and there's no "Unblock" button lol

Comment: I only know it appears if the file is local. Your file isn't. But here's no reason to think explorer acts any different. Go to that machine and right click it.

Comment: Do a `dir "\\10.0.24.103\somePath\batchFile.bat" /r` and see if you have a zone stream.